# Validating type of input AND range of integers in Java

Tags: java, validation, if-statement, while-loop, integer

Here's a snippet of code I'm working on for a larger project:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void getZip() {
   boolean shallNPass=true;
   int zip=0;

   System.out.print("Enter zipcode: ");
    while(shallNPass) {
        if(in.hasNextInt()) {
            zip = in.nextInt();
            if(zip>999 && zip<100000)
                zip = in.nextInt();
            else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect length for a zip. Try again");
                System.out.print("Enter zipcode: ");
                continue;
            }
            shallNPass = false;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Please use an integer.");
            System.out.print("Enter zipcode: ");
            continue;
        }
        shallNPass = false;
    }   shallNPass = true;  //RESETTING SHALLNPASS

    System.out.println(zip);
    //In actuality I continue to do another similar while loop similar after this
    //but I don't want to make this longer, so used a print
}
```

It's based off a solution that I found here concerning validation that the user enters a value of a certain type. I just took it a step farther and tried to validate that the value entered is between 1000 & 99999.

The issue I'm having, is that after entering an integer of the correct length I have to enter it again in order to get the program to continue to the next line of code. I don't have this issue when validating the type, just when I add the length.

How can I fix this? I've tried all sorts of tricks with continue, break, and nested loops, I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Simple but ugly way is to replace the second `zip = in.nextInt();` by `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see here that you're asking for it again:

```
if (in.hasNextInt()) {
    zip = in.nextInt(); // asking for input once
    if (zip > 999 && zip < 100000) {
        zip = in.nextInt(); // if validates, you're asking for input again
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect length for a zip. Try again");
        System.out.print("Enter zipcode: ");
        continue;
    }
    shallNPass = false;
}
```

Restructure your if-else block:

```
if (zip <= 999 || zip >= 100000) {
    System.out.println("Incorrect length for a zip. Try again");
    System.out.print("Enter zipcode: ");
    continue;
}
```

You only need to prompt again if it does NOT validate properly; thus, you don't need an `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, here's my fixed solution. Opted to keep the expanded nested if statement in the interest of getting rid of the continues. It felt a little more straight forward to read without them.

```
System.out.print("Enter zipcode: ");
    while(shallNPass) {
        if(in.hasNextInt()) {
            zip = in.nextInt();
            if(zip>999 && zip<100000) 
                shallNPass=false;
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Wrong length for a zip.");
                System.out.print("Enter zipcode: ");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Please use an integer.");
            System.out.print("Enter zipcode: ");
            in.next();
        }
    }   shallNPass = true;  //RESETTING SHALLNPASS
```